# Multiple condition in on clause linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to achieve following SQL statement through LINQ but couldn't succeed so for

```
   DECLARE @_Date datetime = '2014-02-25'
    SELECT  Title,FromDate,ToDate
    FROM    Positions INNER JOIN
           PositionHistories ON Positions.PositionID = PositionHistories.PositionID
           and @_Date BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate
where PositionID=58
```

When I write the following LINQ query

```
    from p in db.Positions 
    join ph in PositionHistories.where((x => x.FromDate <= _Date && x.ToDate >= _Date)
    on p.PositionID equals ph.PositionID
    where p.PositionID=58
select new
    {
     Title,
    FromDate,
    ToDate
    }
```

I get the following SQL output

```
SELECT  Title,FromDate,ToDate
FROM    Positions INNER JOIN       
PositionHistories ON Positions.PositionID = PositionHistories.PositionID              
where PositionID=58  and @_Date BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate
```

which is not desired. Any suggession

Comment: Why you don't like the SQL LINQ produces? You'll get the same results, and SQL Server is smart enough to optimize both queries to exact same execution plan. You should check it.

Comment: And you can also create view in SQL and Linq to view.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek  From SQL point of view both gives different output

Comment: @Farhad I know I can write view.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/03/15/sql-server-interesting-observation-of-on-clause-on-left-join-how-on-clause-effects-resultset-in-left-join/

Comment: For simplicity I write the inner join example here

Comment: @Zia For inner join there is no difference, so LINQ provider can choose a way to generate SQL query. As long as you get correct results. Use outer join in you LINQ query, and you'll see that it will be translated correctly, with filter before join.